# Postgres multi column value based constraint?

Tags: postgresql

```
key            | value   |  other         
----------------------------------- 
key1           | red     |  r1          
key1           | blue    |  b1  
key1           | blue    |  b2         
key2           | green   |  g
key2           | yellow  |  y
```

In postgres, how do i define a constraint such that a value is only associated to one of the keys. Ex: `red` can only have `key1`, `green` can only have `key2`?

```
key            | value   |  other         
----------------------------------- 
key1           | red     |  r1          
key1           | blue    |  b1  
key1           | blue    |  b2         
key2           | blue    |  r4
key2           | yellow  |  y
```

This is not allowed because value `blue` is associated to `key1` & `key2`.

Comment: To rephrase your question, you're trying to enforce a one-to-one mapping between unique keys and values, correct?

Comment: kind of like an injective function. distinct elements on the left(key) cannot map to the same elements on the right(value).

Comment: @Bharath To clarify, your table can contain multiple rows with the same key, correct? And if the same key is repeated, they all must have the same value field?

Comment: @SamChoukri updated the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper solution is a redesign so that you normalize the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE part1 (
   value text PRIMARY KEY,
   key text NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE part2 (
   value REFERENCES part1(value) NOT NULL,
   other text NOT NULL
);
```

Then the constraint is guaranteed by the table structure, and you don't have to store redundant data multiple times.

Comment: Thanks laurenz. This is the correct design to enforce the constraint. I wasn't sure thinking it will create too many tables.